# AttributeError when variable placed in different spot (list comprehension)

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

The following code works fine when HD is placed anywhere but right before the return statement. When HD is placed between D and the return statement, it gives an AttributeErrror. The same goes for the N variable - if I place it down the bottom, it doesn't work. I'm sure there's a good explanation for this that I'd love to learn if anyone would have a moment.

**Works**

```
def marksdistribution(D):
    N = [s for s in D.values() if s < 50]
    HD = [s for s in D.values() if s > 80]
    P = [s for s in D.values() if s >= 50 and s < 60]
    Cr = [s for s in D.values() if s >= 60 and s < 70]
    D = [s for s in D.values() if s >= 70 and s < 80]
    return HD

print(marksdistribution({"Fred":55, "James":90, "Jemima":71}))
```

**Does not work**

```
def marksdistribution(D):
    N = [s for s in D.values() if s < 50]
    P = [s for s in D.values() if s >= 50 and s < 60]
    Cr = [s for s in D.values() if s >= 60 and s < 70]
    D = [s for s in D.values() if s >= 70 and s < 80]
    HD = [s for s in D.values() if s > 80]
    return HD
    
print(marksdistribution({"Fred":55, "James":90, "Jemima":71}))
```

**Error message**

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is,

```
D = [s for s in D.values() if s >= 70 and s < 80]
```

This line replaces the value in the variable D that you have sent inside the function. Therefore the expected type is no longer a dictionary but a list.

Have a different variable name for D and try.

```
def marksdistribution(D):
    N = [s for s in D.values() if s < 50]
    P = [s for s in D.values() if s >= 50 and s < 60]
    Cr = [s for s in D.values() if s >= 60 and s < 70]
    D1 = [s for s in D.values() if s >= 70 and s < 80]
    HD = [s for s in D.values() if s > 80]
    return HD


print(marksdistribution({"Fred": 55, "James": 90, "Jemima": 71}))
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, how did I not see/think of that - I was pulling my hair out! Thank you!